# left right floating div according to width of parent div

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry if the title is confusing as I couldn't find the appropriate title for my problem.But definitely I know what I am trying to achieve.

If you look the dropdown of http://applearn.tv/ then you can see on mouseover the dropdown is changing it's direction ie if mouseover on first menu then the div displays from right to left and for the last menu it displays from left to right.Currently this is static but I would like to get the concept of the same thing using jquery.

Sorry I don't have the jsfiddle for this.

Please let me know if there is any kind of tutorial or fiddle.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest, do some research, make some effort and post some fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Nathan...Let me try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out the position of dropdown box by checking window width, dropdown box width & navigation item position left

You cantry this logic, id left co-ordinate of current navigation comes in left half of the window then apply float:left else apply float:right

Code:

```
    $('.navLink').click(showNavigation);

    function showNavigation() {

        var navigationItem = $(this);//Assuming this is anchor tag
        var holderItem = navigationItem.next('div.navigationItem');
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var navigationLeft = navigationItem.offset().left;

        //Find current position, if this is greater than half of window width then apply float:left else float:right
        var currentPosition = (windowWidth - navigationLeft) + navigationItem.width();

        //class float_left_class stands of float:left and class float_rght_class stands for float:float_rght_class
        var holderClass = (currentPosition > windowWidth / 2) ? 'float_left_class' : 'float_rght_class';

        //remove previosly added class and add new class
        holderItem.removeClass('float_left_class float_rght_class').addClass(holderClass);

        //then show holder item
        holderItem.show();
    }
```

Style:

```
.float_left_class{
    float:left;
}

.float_rght_class{
    float:right;
}
.navigationItem{
    display:none;
}
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="navLink">Navigation 1 </a>
        <div class="navigationItem">Detail</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Anjith...Currently just researching jquery tutorials how to get the position of the div and it's main container width.The position left and right has to be dynamic.

Comment: Brilliant!!...I am going to try this logic now.My html is bit different but definitely this logic is going to work.

Comment: Your create a fiddle for this with your css styles so that we can help you.

Comment: It's solved.Actually my code is different.I have a slider and onclick any item within that slider a invisible div from left to right or right to left will appear just beside the item.Now I was stuck with the calculation part.I have taken the position left of the item and position left of the div content then subtract the itempos from divcontentpos.I will try to show you the endresult soon in a browser.Thank you so much for your idea.That's what I needed.